# Clarification on Automatic Failover Rules in SQL Server Availability Groups

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, failover

I'm configuring a SQL Server Availability Group with three replicas: `node1\inst`, `node2\inst`, and `node3\inst`. I have set `node1\inst` for automatic failover with synchronous commit, while `node2\inst` and `node3\inst` are configured for manual failover.

[image]

I have a couple of questions about the failover behavior:

1. When `node1\inst` is the primary replica and encounters an issue, will it automatically failover to `node2` or `node3` even if they are set for manual failover? Additionally, does automatic failover only occur between automatic-failover-and-synchronous-commit replicas?
2. If `node2` becomes the primary replica and a problem occurs, does it still adhere to its manual failover setting, or will there be an automatic failover to `node1`?

I am trying to understand the intricacies of failover mechanics within SQL Server Availability Groups to ensure a reliable high availability setup. Insights into how automatic failover decisions are determined in these configurations would be extremely helpful.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When `node1\inst` is the primary replica and encounters an issue, will it automatically failover to node2 or node3 even if they are set for manual failover?

It will not, you'd need a minimum of 2 replicas to be [set to synchronous commit *and* automatic failover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/failover-and-failover-modes-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver16#RequiredConditions) in order to have an automatic failover.

> Additionally, does automatic failover only occur between automatic-failover-and-synchronous-commit replicas?

Yes (same link above).

> If node2 becomes the primary replica and a problem occurs, does it still adhere to its manual failover setting, or will there be an automatic failover to node1?

It will still *not* automatically failover because the minimum requirements have not been met (same link as #1).

> Insights into how automatic failover decisions are determined in these configurations would be extremely helpful.

Here are the Docs on [how automatic failover works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/failover-and-failover-modes-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver16#HowAutoFoWorks). If you have further questions, please feel free to ask them in new questions.

Comment: Hi Sean, If automatic failover is not possible, does this mean that if a problem occurs on node1\inst, it will simply go down, and node2\inst and node3\inst will remain unusable at that time?

Comment: @Justalearner Yes and no. If `node1\inst` goes down then you'll be unable to query either of the two remaining instances (they will be in resolving), however as an administrator you _could_ force a failover to another node with potential data loss. This will not be done automatically because there is a chance for data loss.